# How do we create a custom drop down list in android which is different than spinner? Please help me with the code

Tags: android

The drop down list should have a fixed predefined name unlike spinner.
When its elements are clicked, they should pass an Intent to go to their corresponding activity.
Hoping for a good code.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want it to be different from a Spinner? You can set the spinner to start an activity when an item is selected.

```
    playlistsSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int pos, long arg3) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, yourOtherActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("extra-pos", pos);

            //or, if you want different activites then: 
            Intent newActivity;
            switch (pos) {
            case 0:
                newActivity = new Intent(this, activityB.class); 
                break;
            case 1: 
                newActivity = new Intent(this, activityC.class); 
                break;
            default:
                //do nothing
                break;
            }
            if (newActivity != null) {
                startActivity(newActivity);
            }
        }
```

You can also customize the look of the spinner to your like.